# Keen.js Hardcode graph data

Tags: javascript, html, keen-io

I downloaded a sample which users Keen.js to pull data for a pie chart.

I just need to hardcode some data into the chart,

For example 50% pass, 50% fail.

```
var pageviews_static = new Keen.Query("count", {
    eventCollection: "pageviews",
    groupBy: "user.device_info.browser.family",
    timeframe: {
      start: "2014-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      end: "2014-05-05T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  });

  client.draw(pageviews_static, document.getElementById("chart-02"), {
    chartType: "piechart",
    title: false,
    height: 250,
    width: "auto",
    chartOptions: {
      chartArea: {
        height: "85%",
        left: "5%",
        top: "5%",
        width: "100%"
      },
      pieHole: .4
    }
  });
```

How can I hardcode pageview_static to 50% pass, 50% fail

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the google charts options that are exposed by [keen.js](https://github.com/keen/keen-js).

Customized labels for the data: https://github.com/keen/keen-js/blob/master/docs/visualization.md#customized-labels

and Custom data objects "Keen.Dataset: https://github.com/keen/keen-js/tree/master/docs/dataset#keendataset

```
var chart = new Keen.Dataviz()
    .el(document.getElementById("chart"))
    .chartType('piechart')
    .parseRawData({ result: [
        { label: 'Pass', value: 50 },
        { label: 'Fail', value: 50 }
    ] })
    .title('Pass/Fail Rate')
    .height(240)
    .render();
```